# Unable to disconnect socket into ionic application

Tags: typescript, socket.io, ionic3

I am not able to socket disconnect into ionic application. I have socket.on into the constructor of common page in providers. I want to disconnect socket into a function on the same file from where application logout is called.

But I am unable to disconnect the socket. I am multiple socket.on('event') on multiple emit into application. Can anyone help me out?

[sample code which contain function have described into problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrIEv.png)

Comment: a piece of your provider's code please?

Comment: @PhoenixBlue The sample code has been added.